# How to find and add frequency column for ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I am a beginner at python, so bear with me!

My dataset is from excel and I was curious how to find and add a frequency column for my ID.

I first performed the groupby function for ID and date by doing:

```
dfcount = dfxyz.groupby(["ID", "Date"])
```

and then found the mean by doing:

```
dfcount1 = dfcount.mean()
```

The output i got was:

[image]

What I am trying to do is get the frequency number beside it like this:

[image: Image2]

I did not know how to copy python code, so I uploaded pictures! Sorry! Any help is appreciated for what code I can use to count the frequency for each ID AFTER I find the mean of the groupby columns.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The groupby method is cumcount, but this question needs to be improced with some runable code. The easiest way to get the code is to simply copy and paste (rather than take screenshots).

Comment: OK i figured it out, but how would I add the cumcount values as a colummn in my dataset. Or, how do I groupby the comcount as I want to find the mean for all the "1" value for cumcount, "2" value for cumcount, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `groupby` with `cumcount`

```
df['Freq']=(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1).values
```

Comment: The values is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df['column_name'].value_counts()
```

[value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) - Returns object containing counts of unique values